# Stack header vertically in "steps" using css

Tags: html, css

I have a header that's being pulled from the database and I need to style it sort of like steps. I can't access HTML directly and add line breakers, etc. Is there a way to target each word somehow or make it stack like this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: No, you would need to be able to change the HTML structure in order to accomplish this layout.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript? If so my updates answer might suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript you could do something like this:

```html
<p>
  Know Our Needs.
</p>
```

```js
let t = document.querySelector('p')
let txt = t.textContent
let stack  = txt.split(' ')

let d = document.createElement('div')
d.classList.add('wrapper')

stack.forEach((s) => {
  p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = s
  d.append(p)
})

document.body.replaceChild(d, t)
```

combined with a little css

```css
.wrapper {
  color: red;
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 16rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 2.25rem;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5.25rem;
}
.wrapper p {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper p:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.wrapper p:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

https://codepen.io/bluebrown/pen/qBEdLmY